# AJAX response data containing HTML and li to option convert in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have call a url using jquery it return

```
function loadAllCompany(fileName) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: host + fileName,
    success: function (data) {
    // i want to put data variables data in select/options
});
```

it returns data like below

```
<div class="total-num">Company (58)</div>
    <ul class="company-view list"> 
    <li data-type="company-list" data-id="6488" data_domain="company2.portal.gov.bd">company2 </li>
    <li data-type="company-list" data-id="5934" data_domain="company3.portal.gov.cc"> company3</li>
    <li data-type="company-list" data-id="126" data_domain="company4.portal.gov.bd">company4 </li>
 </ul>
```

How can I read the `data` variable's `data-id` attribute and put it into the select/option value?

```
<select name="company-list" id="">
    <option data-type="company-list" data-id="6488" data_domain=" value=""></option>
    <option data-type=" company-list" data-id="5934" data_domain=" value=""></option>
    <option data-type=" company-list" data-id="126" data_domain=" value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you not have any access to the server side code? It would be a ***far*** better solution to correct the HTML that's sent, or better yet return JSON, not to hack around the response on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to return easy to use server response data such as JSON. However, I have a solution for what you have at the moment in case you are not able to return other data response from your server.

```js
const responseHtml = data; // The response data from the server
const companyList = $(responseHtml).filter('.company-view'); // Get the UL element
const companyListItems = companyList.children(); // Get the LI elements

/* Create the select field */
const _selectField = $('<select/>', {
    'name' : 'company-list',
    'id' : ''
});

/* Iterate through each of the company list items */
$.each(companyListItems, function(i, item) {
    const _this = $(this);

    /* Create the option element and add all the attributes */
    const _opetionEl = $('<option/>', {
        'data-type' : _this.data('type'),
        'data-id' : _this.data('id'),
        'data-domain' : _this.data('domain'),
        'value' : _this.data('id'),
        'html' : _this.html().trim()
    });
    
    /* Append the created element into the select field */
    _selectField.append(_opetionEl);
});
    
/* Attach the select field to the document body element or any other element */
$('body').prepend(_selectField); // Show select field in the top of the page
```

I created the solution based on the data you have provided and have not tested the code but I believe it works.